# laravel SSH exceeding execution time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to use the Remote ssh functionality in laravel. I keep receiving a "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded" I understand I can set this timeout, but the problem is it should not be taking that long to do an `ls` .

I am able to run the following

`exec("ssh -i /path/to/key user@host ls", $out, $code);`

without an issue, so this is not a problem with firewall.

but I am unable to run this:

```
  SSH::run(array(
          'ls'
          ), function($line) {
     echo $line . PHP_EOL;
  });
```

I am not sure why this is hanging and timing out.

I would also like to know if there is a way to specify `ssh -o` options, because for some I may need to specify `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`

Comment: Are you sure your `app/config/remote.php` is correct?

Comment: yes, I have tried with  a key and without key and with a password

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this, it turns out my openssl library version and header version did not match, this causes phpseclib(the way laravel connects) to use a slower library, which then causes the timeout. as a temporary fix I have modified the following.

[here:](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php)

starting at line 256

from this :

```
       switch (true) {
            case !isset($versions['Header']):
            case !isset($versions['Library']):
            case $versions['Header'] == $versions['Library']:
                define('MATH_BIGINTEGER_OPENSSL_ENABLED', true);
                break;
            default:
                define('MATH_BIGINTEGER_OPENSSL_DISABLE', true);
        }
```

to this:

```
      switch (true) {
            case !isset($versions['Header']):
            case !isset($versions['Library']):
            case $versions['Header'] == $versions['Library']:
                define('MATH_BIGINTEGER_OPENSSL_ENABLED', true);
                break;
            default:
                define('MATH_BIGINTEGER_OPENSSL_ENABLE', true);
        }
```